# Installing tensorflow-data-validation with pip installation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried to install tensorflow-data-validation 0.9.0 with pip installation, but  it keeps giving me the same error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-data-validation...
isn't this version available for windows or i am just missing something?

Comment: What version of python are you trying to install this with? I sometimes get this error when trying to install libraries and I've forgotten to switch my interpreter.

Comment: so i used Python 3.6.2, because tensorflow on windows is compatible just with 3.5 and 3.6

Answer (score 0):

From the [PyPi documentation on tensorflow-data-validation](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-data-validation/) you can see the version compatibility:

> Requires: Python >=2.7,<3

So you won't be able to install it with other versions (like your 3.6.2).

Comment: Correct, this is the same situation I am in (I use tf on Windows). You will not be able to install tensorflow-data-validation while using tensorflow on windows due to the version difference.

Comment: unfortunately, no. You could possibly ask the contributors on github directly (assuming it's on there).